# parallel filters vs series filters

Tags: parallel, series

So I have been having trouble understanding the difference of  Rc filters that have the capacitor in series with the resistance and Rc filters that have the capacitor parallel to the resistance .
To make this more specific , why are both low pass filters? Can all filters be made in parallel and in series?

[image][image]

Comment: The voltage on a capacitor can't change "suddenly". So it will block any fast (high frequency) signals. That's the intuition. The rest is a math.

Comment: They are not both low pass filters. The upper circuit is a high-pass filter.

Comment: Check the circuit at the two extremes. Effective resistance of a capacitor at 0 freq is infinite. Conversely, at infinite freq, the capacitor looks like a short.

Comment: Convert both filters to Z impedance and you'll see that their different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not both low pass filters. The upper circuit is a high-pass filter.

But the fact the capacitor is labelled \$\rm C_f\$ suggests this filter might be used in the feed back path of an op-amp circuit.

In that case, the overall op-amp circuit might very well be a low-pass filter. Because using a high-pass filter to increase the negative feedback at high frequencies will result in reducing the response of the overall op-amp circuit at those frequencies.